# Undefined reference linker error when using 16-byte CAS with GCC

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I'm using GCC 4.7.2 on Debian, and getting linker errors whenever I try to use the `<atomic>` facilities with 16-byte values.  I'm running an x86_64 VM which can support the `CMPXCHG16B` instruction - but even if I didn't have the necessary hardware, I don't see why a linker error should be produced here.  As far as I know, the `<atomic>` library is supposed to fall back on using regular locks if the hardware doesn't support the necessary CAS operation.

Anyway, here's a very simple test case to reproduce this problem:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>

struct foo
{
    std::uint64_t x;
    std::uint64_t y;
};

int main()
{
    std::atomic<foo> f1({0,0});
    foo f2 = {0,0};
    foo f3 = {1,1};
    f1.compare_exchange_strong(f2, f3);
}
```

When I compile this, I get:

```
# g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++11 -g3
/tmp/ccziKZis.o: In function `std::atomic<foo>::compare_exchange_strong(foo&, foo, std::memory_order, std::memory_order)':
/usr/include/c++/4.7/atomic:259: undefined reference to `__atomic_compare_exchange_16'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note that if I change the program so that `foo` is only 8 bytes, I don't get the linker error.  What's going on here?

Comment: Interesting, I can repro this with g++ 4.8.2 and clang++ 3.6. Not sure what the underlying problem is - but seems like a bug in the standard library, or some such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer, once you know it:

Invoke `g++` with `-mcx16`.

The g++ docs say:

> This option will enable GCC to use CMPXCHG16B instruction in
>   generated code.  CMPXCHG16B allows for atomic operations on
>   128-bit double quadword (or oword) data types.  This is useful for
>   high resolution counters that could be updated by multiple
>   processors (or cores).  This instruction is generated as part of
>   atomic built-in functions: see *note Atomic Builtins:: for details.

(Note that this doesn't work for `clang` - I think that is a bug!)

Comment: Huh... strange.  I would think GCC is supposed to just automatically support cmpxchg16b if available, or else fall back on using a lock

Comment: Yes, one would expect so. I think it goes back to some early versions [of Intel's since I seem to remember that AMD had it from the very beginning - but can't say for sure] of x86-64 didn't have this, or some such.

Comment: _I would think GCC is supposed to just automatically support cmpxchg16b if available, or else fall back on using a lock_  Right, but how does the machine you compile on know if cmpxchg16b is available on the machine you run on?  One way is to tell it with a flag.  Another is to have the binary call to a CPU-specific dynamic library, which will do the cmpxchg16b if supported otherwise do the same thing with locks.  Apparently all Pentiums and greater, except a couple 2002 AMD's have had this instruction so it's a shame the compiler doesn't simply generate the instruction.

Comment: As of GCC : "The compiler uses this instruction to implement __sync Builtins.  However, for __atomic Builtins operating on 128-bit integers, a library call is always used."