# error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<_Tp>::atomic()

Tags: c++, c++14

I got this code in cpp (it is a minimal example where I get the error):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

const int N = 128;

template <typename T> struct Element {
    const T * key{nullptr};
    bool occupied{false};

    Element( const T* key, bool occupied ) : key( key ), occupied( occupied ) {}
    Element() : key{}, occupied{} {}
};

template <typename T>
class AtomicHashSet {
    std::atomic<Element<T>> table[N];

public:
    AtomicHashSet() : table{} {}

    size_t hash( const T& key ) const {
        return std::hash<const T>()( &key );
    }

    bool insert( const T& key ) {
        Element<T> e{};
        e.key = &key;
        e.occupied = true;

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
            size_t idx = ( hash( key ) + i ) % N;

            Element<T> empty{};
            if ( table[idx].compare_exchange_strong( empty, e ) ) {
                return true;
            }
            else if ( table[idx].load().key == &key ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    AtomicHashSet<int> set;
    int one = 1;
    std::cout << "insert hello 1: " << set.insert(one) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is shown as follows:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<_Tp>::atomic() [with _Tp = Element<int>]’
     AtomicHashSet() : table{} {}
```

I had the same error before at a different line because I forgot the default constructor in the 'Element' struct. What did I wrong this time?

Can someone help me here? Thanks alot!

Comment: That doesn't look very minimal to me. Do you get the same error with just `std::atomic<int> table[1];`?

Comment: it is the most minimal version I got. How do you mean, with that line of code? like where?

Comment: As your program. OK, you probably also need `#include <atomic>`.

Comment: @melpomene: No If I just call this in the main, I don't get any errors.

Comment: This is a very annoying error.  C++ is getting way too complicated and strict these days.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is confusing.
But the problem is that atomic's constructor is declared as **noexcept**, and your Element's constructor is not, so it cannot be called.
If you add noexcept to Element's constructor it will compile:

```
Element() noexcept : key{}, occupied{} {}
```

Comment: that is very interesting. When doing this, I get this similar error: `error: use of deleted function ‘std::hash<const int>::hash()’
         return std::hash<const T>()( &key );`

Comment: You are attempting to compute hash of a pointer. Use this instead: return std::hash<T>()(key);

Comment: That doesn't change the problem.

Comment: @Xorkox There is no specialization for const types. Why would you write `std::hash<const T>`?

Comment: @Brian: Because if I don't I get this: `In function std::atomic<Element<int> >::load(std::memory_order) const':
/usr/include/c++/6.2.1/atomic:235: undefined reference to __atomic_load_16'`

Answer (score 2):

[`std::atomic`'s default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic) is `noexcept`, so when you try to instantiate it with some type, that type also needs to be `noexcept` default constructible so that the exception specifications match.

```
Element( const T* key, bool occupied ) noexcept : key( key ), occupied( occupied ) {}
Element() noexcept : key{}, occupied{} {}
```

I'd rewrite your second constructor as

```
Element() noexcept = default;  // noexcept is optional here
```

The next problem is with this strange bit of code you have

```
return std::hash<const T>()( &key );
                 ^^^^^       ^^^^
```

`std::hash` doesn't provide specializations for `const` types and you're passing an `int const *` to a function that expects an `int`. Rewrite the above line as

```
return std::hash<T>()( key );
```

With these changes made you'll run into the following linker error

```
undefined reference to `__atomic_load_16'
```

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26689234/241631), to allow gcc to generate instructions for a 16-byte atomic compare exchange, you need to pass `-mcx16` to the compiler. Alternatively, you can pass a `-march`  option, for instance, `-march=native` which will generate the instruction if the machine you're compiling this code on supports it.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b41cec194fc01cd2)